# How to add non-vertx-module dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, vert.x

How can I add a module (a simple self-written Java library with some common utilities) to a Vert.x multi-module project?

I got an exemplary root `pom.xml`:

```
<modules>
  <module>common</module> <!-- this is the simple java module //-->
  <module>core</module>
  <module>web-server</module>
  <module>business</module>
</modules>
```

The `pom.xml` of the common module (non-Vert.x):

```
<artifactId>common</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Project - Some common utilities</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

And the `pom.xml` of the Vert.x module which has a dependency to the common module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> <!-- without i got an error[1] //->
</dependency>
```

> [1] ... [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:copy-dependencies
>   (copy-mod-dependencies-to-target) on project business : Artifact has
>   not been packaged yet. When used on reactor artifact, copy should be
>   executed after packaging: see MDEP-187. -> [Help 1]

With the given scope it builds successfully but when i start the Vert.x module I got a `NoClassDefFoundError`. My IDE does not report any problem before.

I know there is a way of non-runnable-modules with "include" in `mod.json` but I guess the better solution for my problem is the way of a simple Java module included while build, isn't it?

Comment: I assume the common module will be used by other modules?

Comment: Yup, this was my intention.

Comment: Why do you use `copy-dependencies` in a module where you (I assume) just use the commons module? You should define it as a dependency in your pom.

Comment: I also use 3rd-party libraries like apaches commons and so on and without this goal these libraries are not copied and the running vertx-module spits out the NoClassDefFoundError for these 3rd-party libraries.

Comment: And the problem, if i use the "install" goal (which may be solves all the problems) i got this error: http://pastebin.com/XJqtTYuR

Comment: Take a deep look into the following example: https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee/  cause you seemed to be using extremly old plugins and you haven't understood the maven reactor and the build order and how it's calculated. This can be done only via dependencies between the appropriate modules. There usually never a need to do a `dependency:copy-dependencies` (only in extreme rare cases).

Comment: Thats the biggest problem, i'm not rly familiar with maven, until now i had always build manager which handled all the maven stuff which i just had to use :) But now i have to understand it, at least basically, for my own purposes.
For the completeness, my project based upon this structure (https://github.com/nscavell/multi-example), also the maven stuff comes from this example which i just want to extend for my needs.